# Multi-Level Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

Please can you show me the simplest way to implement multi-level comparator:
I have an employee class and I want to compare them by salary, this is done by implementing a comparator :

```
public class SalaryComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        return   (int) (o1.getSalary()-o2.getSalary());
    }
}
```

Now if the salary is the same I want to compare them by Lastname or ID

How can I do it ?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the [`Comparator` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). In detail, look at `Comparator::comparing` and `Comparator::thenComparing`.

Comment: Assuming the salaries are `double` or `float` (otherwise why cast to `int`), casting to `int` here is buggy because it can round results down to zero, making them appear equal when they are not.

Comment: @kaya3 Salaries are double and the methode returning type is int ?! how can I get around this ?

Comment: @Rami You can (and should) use the `Double.compare` function: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double- But for this case you don't need to write your own comparator class at all (as discussed in my answer).

Comment: @Kaya3 Okey thank you I know it I just forget as I learn ..... I'm just learning interfaces that is why I want to write my comparator hope that this won't disturb members so much

Comment: I see; if it's for practice/learning then by all means, write it as your own class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Comparator.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) method. The [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method also simplifies this so you don't have to write your own classes implementing `Comparator`:

```java
Comparator<Employee> cmp = new SalaryComparator()
    .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getLastName))
    .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getID));
```

You can even eliminate your `SalaryComparator` class entirely:

```java
Comparator<Employee> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)
    .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getLastName))
    .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getID));
```

If your methods return primitive types (e.g. if `getSalary` returns `double`), use e.g. the [`comparingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) method instead of `comparing`. There are also [`comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and [`comparingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-).